# pasar datos de una tabla sql impresa en html a una ventana modal en jquery

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

**Escenario:**

- Dispongo de una tabla sql llamada códigos que contiene un listado de
  trabajos a calificar.
- La tabla se imprime en formato html en una página que utiliza
  Bootstrap (incluye jquery).
- La tabla html muestra los siguientes datos: id del trabajo, nombre,
  fecha, enlace al detalle, y dos botones para eliminar o calificar el
  trabajo correspondiente.

**Objetivo:**

- Necesito que al hacer clic en el botón de calificar de cada fila o
  trabajo a calificar, se abra una modal.
- Quiero que los datos del registro estén disponibles dentro de la
  modal que se ha abierto en paso anterior.
- La modal también debe contener un campo de texto editable que permita
  modificar la calificación del trabajo al hacer clic en un botón "Enviar calificación".

**Bloqueo:**

- Para poder editar la calificación correspondiente al botón de un
  registro concreto, **no sé cómo enviar la id desde la ventana activa a
  la modal**.

> ***NOTA:*** *Todo debe ser dentro de la misma pagina.*

***CÓDIGO DE LA TABLA***

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Trabajo</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Acción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
include("../../conexion.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM codigos";
$resultado = $conexion -> query($query);
while($row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id'];?></th>
      <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
      <td><a href="javascript: void(0)"  class="btn btn-success show-modal-preview" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Ver</a></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></td>
      <td>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-info show-modal-qualification" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Calificar</a><!-- Botón que abre el modal -->
<a href="borrar_codigo.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
</td>

    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***Código del modal***

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="qualification" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Trabajo</h5>
      </div>
<div class="modal-body" id="success">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar Javascript para lograrlo, por ejemplo con el atributo data 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos

```js
$('.show-modal-qualification').click(function() {
  $('#qualification').modal('show');
   $('span').text($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-info show-modal-qualification" data-id="1">Calificar</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn btn-info show-modal-qualification" data-id="2">Calificar</a>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="qualification" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Trabajo</h5>
        <p>El id es: <span></span><p>
      </div>
<div class="modal-body" id="success">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```